# What are the default permissions for the /usr/share/applications folder?

Tags: permissions, directory

Accidentally typed in the following command and messed up permissions.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/share/applications
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files inside `/usr/share/applications` are owned by root:root. Here's the proof:

```
% sudo find /usr/share/applications ! \( -user root -a -group root \)
%
```

So to fix that just run:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/share/applications
```